# AR Core in Unity: How to change surface shader material to support normal maps?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, arcore

I need to assign a shader that supports normal maps to the PlanGrid material in the HelloAR scene of the AR Core Unity package.

The problem is, every other shader I assign to this material is rendered with an average color calculated by the colors on the assigned texture.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

EDIT:
Okay I modified the original ARCore shader to be able to support normal maps, the new problem now is that the normal map is not shown in the generated plane but only on other 3D objects the scene, similarly to the original problem with the textures.

Comment: To me that sounds like the object's UVs aren't set up correctly

Comment: @Draco18s the problem is that the same shader applied to another object in the scene renders the texture correctly, but when I apply it to the AR plane of the example the texture is rendered with an uniform color instead.

Comment: Interesting. I can't think of what would do that off the top of my head. :\